# How to get app accesstoken for marketing API Facebook

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api

We want to use the Marketing API from Facebook. We have build an app which allows us to create ads. 
Now we want to make the app public, but we need an access token to grant access to the app.
I can create an access_token from my app dashboard > Marketing API > Tools, but that key expires after some time (do not know the exact lifetime) so I need a way to get an fresh access token.

I tried to get the key using this request:

```
function refreshToken(callback){
    request.get({
        headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
        url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=' + appId + '&client_secret=' + appSecret + '&grant_type=client_credentials',
        method: 'GET'
    }, function (error, response, body) {
        callback(null, JSON.parse(body));
    });
}
```

Which gives me `APP_ID|ACCESS_TOKEN` in the `body.access_token`.

> {"data":{"error":{"message":"Invalid OAuth access
>   token.","type":"OAuthException","code":190,"fbtrace_id":"EhprtaKcDFj"}},"status":400,"config":{"method":"POST","transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","headers":{"Accept":"application/json,
>   text/plain,
>   */*"},"url":"https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/act_[my_advertiser_id]/adimages","data":{}},"statusText":""}

It looks like it isn't a valid access_token. When I compare that access_code with the one I get from the app dashboard, I see that the valid code (from the dashboard) is a quite longer than the code from the request.

How can I get a valid access_token to access the Marketing API functions?

Comment: _"How can I get a valid access_token to access the Marketing API functions?"_ - you already did ... all you gotta do now is stop trying to "split" it ... (But of course you got to verify whether the request you want to make even works with an _app_ access token - my guess, most likely not.)

Comment: You might want to read https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension